# Why does the Model M (USB) ignore some keystroke combinations?

Tags: keyboard

I've got a 2015-issue Model M keyboard (by Unicomp, 122 keys, German layout, USB), which ignores certain keystrokes resp. keystroke combinations:

- Page Down
- Caps Lock
- Right Ctrl + X (does work with left Ctrl)
- Right Alt (+ Shift) + S (Right Alt is used as ISO Level 3 shift)

I'm using the board on an OpenSuSE Leap 15.2 system.

A little research by using `xev` showed me that in these cases, the key affected does not emit a scancode. In the combinations, the Ctrl resp. Alt keystroke is registered, whereas the letter key itself is ignored. I removed and reattached the controller board to the conductor foils, but no use.

Does anybody know what's wrong here?

**UPDATE:** Just tried it out on a Raspi, also with `xev`. Exactly the same behavior. And: As the board is 6 years old, it's already out of warranty.

Comment: it *sounds* like the keyboard is defective.  Obviously, test on another computer to see if the problem persists.  Test a *different* keyboard on your computer and see if the problem persists.  Contact Unicomp for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after disassembling the keyboard, it turned out that the conductive structures on the plastic sheets were **corroded** and didn't conduct electricity properly any more:

[image]

As the manufacturer no longer has these sheets in stock, I had to replace the whole keyboard. :-(